# Object with origin set to geometry not at center when coordinates are set to 0,0,0

Tags: origin

When importing glTF models from Sketchfab sometimes they are not at the center even after setting origin to geometry and setting coordinates to 0,0,0. Frame selected show only these parts, the ball is the whole model. No modifiers.

Blender 2.83.3

Model https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/sci-fi-drone-74a5a6bcc9cf4a9f877364ab700623ba

[image: screenshot]

Comment: it looks like there's a line, so check if your object doesn't have a parent/constraint and disable it

Comment: Object > Parent > Clear parent helped, please post it as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a thin line, it means that your object has a parent and that its location values will remain the ones before parenting wherever it is now in your scene, you need to:

- Go in the *Properties panel > Object > Relations > Parent* and remove the parent (yes, cruel).
- Or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear Parent*.
- Or header menu > *Object > Parent > Clear Parent*.

Comment: I have it under Object > Parent, not under Relations, are you sure it should be Relations?

Comment: oh ok yes if you go through the horizontal menu bar but I was going through the Properties panel (on the right), it allows you to know what is the parent. Even simpler: alt P > Clear Parent